# Проблема с загрузкой диска на VPS процессом jbd2

Tags: linux, vps, файловая-система, highload, ext4

На моем VPS стало все чаще происходить "зависания" пишущих (Insert, Update, Replace) запросов к базе данных. Каждые 1-10 минут на 2-30 секунд. Перебрав множество настроек mysql и даже переустановив mysql сервер, я убедился что проблема не в нем.
Однако нашел вот кое-что.

Согласно этой [статье](http://www.chileoffshore.com/en/interesting-articles/126-linux-wait-io-problem) все тесты показывают аналогичную проблему.

> ```
> while true; do date; ps auxf | awk '{if($8=="D") print $0;}'; sleep 1; done :
> ```

```
root       322  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        D    Sep23   0:48  \_ [jbd2/vda1-8]
Tue Sep 27 19:21:06 CEST 2016
root       322  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        D    Sep23   0:48  \_ [jbd2/vda1-8]
Tue Sep 27 19:21:07 CEST 2016
root       322  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        D    Sep23   0:48  \_ [jbd2/vda1-8]
Tue Sep 27 19:21:08 CEST 2016
root       322  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        D    Sep23   0:48  \_ [jbd2/vda1-8]
Tue Sep 27 19:21:09 CEST 2016
root       322  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        D    Sep23   0:48  \_ [jbd2/vda1-8]
Tue Sep 27 19:21:10 CEST 2016
root       322  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        D    Sep23   0:48  \_ [jbd2/vda1-8]
Tue Sep 27 19:21:11 CEST 2016
root       322  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        D    Sep23   0:48  \_ [jbd2/vda1-8]
Tue Sep 27 19:21:12 CEST 2016
root       322  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        D    Sep23   0:48  \_ [jbd2/vda1-8]
Tue Sep 27 19:21:13 CEST 2016
root       322  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        D    Sep23   0:48  \_ [jbd2/vda1-8]
Tue Sep 27 19:21:14 CEST 2016
root       322  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        D    Sep23   0:48  \_ [jbd2/vda1-8]
Tue Sep 27 19:21:15 CEST 2016
root       322  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        D    Sep23   0:48  \_ [jbd2/vda1-8]
Tue Sep 27 19:21:16 CEST 2016
```

Как видно процесс [jbd2/vda1-8] загружает IO диска с флагом D (Uninterruptible sleep). Именно в этот момент запросы к базе данных зависают.

В статье предлагается следующее решение:

> First of all, the reason of high WA is not always the same. But the solution will always on those processes which are with STAT as D. In this case, the configuration of "Journal Disk" should be reconsidered. If the server is a machine for development, it is not recommended to use Journal to protect the hard disk. If the server is a product server, some kind of RAID should be used to protect the failure of disks.
>   So, in my recommendation, take off the Journal any way.

Хостер (ovh.com) говорит что у них все в порядке. Могу ли я сделать что-либо со своей стороны VPS?

Comment: Посмотрите, у Вас на сервере ни где нет очень большого количества мелких файлов, как то: логи, сессии и т.п.? Сервер какую роль выполняет?

Comment: Сервер держит сайт под управлением cpanel.

Comment: Я бы поискал каталог в котором лежит очень много файлов. php кэширование используется?

Answer (score 1):

У меня были проблемы с jbd2 - временами так увеличивал нагрузку что приводил к перезапуску демонов с помощью monit.
После долгих мучений выяснилось что нагрузка создавалась mysql из за множества INSERT и UPDATE. Сброс на диск после каждой транзакции.
База у меня InnoDB. Прописал в настройках mysql:

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 384M
innodb_log_file_size = 16M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2
```

Рестарт mysql и все начало летать.
На сервере 1Гб оперативки. База 25мб.